# How do I use switch statements inside if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that can decide what mechanism a organic reaction will go through using a series of if else and switch statements.

Could you guys help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm having a problem getting the first if else statement to work. The program runs on my computer(I'm using the BlueJ editor), but when I respond to the first question "Is it soluble in solution?" it defaults to the else statement. The switch statements on the inside of the if else statement works fine by itself.

Can I use switch statements inside if else statements? Is there an easier way to program this?

Could you also explain why it doesn't work, or why another method would be more efficient?

Thanks a ton :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
      /**
        * This program will decide what mechanism a reaction will undergo given information about the reactants.
        * I will also include a mechanism to give a rudimentary explanation of the decision making process to
       * get the reaction mechanism.
       */
public class mechanism
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, this program is designed to figure out what mechanism a reaction will under go.");
        //The decision tree will be a series of if-else statements. If I find a better method, I will use that

        System.out.println("Is the reactant soluble in the solvent? Answer in yes or no.");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Solubility = keyboard.next(); //Defines if the reactant is soluble in the solvent
        String functional = "unassigned";//Defines if the functional roup is primary secondary or tertiary
        String Base = "unassigned";//Defines the strength of the base if needed
        String Polar = "unassigned";//Defines if the reactant is polarizable
        String Solvent = "unassigned"; //Defines if the solvent is protic or aprotic

        if ( Solubility == "yes" )
        {

            System.out.println("Is the functional group attached to a primary, secondary, or tertiary carbon?");
            System.out.println(" Answer in p for primary, s for secondary, and t for tertiary.");

            keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            functional = keyboard.next();

                  switch (functional){
                      case "p":   System.out.println("All unimolecular reactions are ruled out, leaving E2 and Sn2.");
                            System.out.println("Is the reactant a strong base? Answer in y for yes or n for no");

                            keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                            Base = keyboard.next();
                                if (Base == "y" ){
                                    System.out.println("The reaction undergoes E2");
                            }    else{
                                    System.out.println("The reaction undergoes Sn2");
                        }

                            break;
                        case "s":  System.out.println("No reactions have been ruled out.");
                                   System.out.println("Is the reactant a strong base? Answer in y or n");

                                   keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                                   Base = keyboard.next();
                                   if( Base == "y" ){
                                       System.out.println("yay");
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("whatever");
                                    }
                                   break;
                        case "t": System.out.println("tertiary");
                            break;

                    }
        } 
        else{
            System.out.println("No reaction will occur");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: Have you already printed and verified the value of `Solubility`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's another one of those mistakes that you and I will make once in a while.

Short answer: **You can't use == to compare strings!**

Long answer:

In your if statements, you are comparing strings with `==`. You should *never* ***EVER*** do that. The `==` compares the memory addresses of the two operands if they are not a primitive. I know you want to check if the *characters* of the two strings are the same. But two strings with the same characters may not have the same memory address!

What you should do is use the `equals` method to compare strings, like this:

```
if (Solubility.equals("yes"))
```

You can also use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method. It does what it says on the lid. Remember to change all the other if statements as well!

Moreover, you cannot use switch statements to switch a string. But seeing you didn't recieve any compiler error, I think you are using Java 8.

But if you are not using Java 8, the best way IMO to resolve this is to switch a `Character`.

```
char functionalChar = functional.charAt(0);
switch (functionalChar) {
    case 'p': // remember to use single quotes!
    ...
}
```

Although this is not the biggest problem, it is still worth correcting:

You only need to instantiate `Scanner` once.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use a switch statement for multiple input types - even within an if statement.

Your problem is that you keep re-initializing the Scanner object.

Once you have initialized the Scanner:

```
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then elsewhere where you would like to receive input, just re-use it:

```
//keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // You don't need this line
Base = keyboard.next();
```

Also, the reason that you are never entering your if statement is the way you are comparing `Solubility` with'Yes'. For Strings, you should use either `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase` if case does not matter.

Change the if statement to the following line and your code will work as expected:

```
    if ( Solubility.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
```

Comment: I don't think this is the main problem. Don't you think the `solubility == "yes"` looks more wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct @Sweeper, was getting there. I was trying to verify if there was any other issues before updating the answer.